# Is there a bug in sklearn's stratified sampling module?

Tags: machine-learning

I am following a book on basic machine learning and I come across the following example:

```
# testing the model will be done on the remaining 10000 images
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:],y[:60000], y[60000:]

import numpy as np
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train,y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

y_train_5 = (y_train == 5) # returns numpy array of bools
y_test_5  = (y_test == 5)

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train,y_train_5)

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.base import clone

skfolds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42)

'''
The following code splits the training set into n_splits sets
and trains the model (each iteration) on the union of n_splits -1 
of the sets and tests in on the remaining set. This is carried out
n_splits times.
'''

for train_index, test_index in skfolds.split(X_train,y_train_5):
    clone_clf = clone(sgd_clf)
    X_train_folds = X_train[train_index]
    y_train_folds = y_train_5[train_index]
    print '\n'
    print "train_index "
    print train_index
    print "test_index "
    print test_index
    X_test_fold   = X_train[test_index]
    y_test_fold   = y_train_5[test_index]

    clone_clf.fit(X_train_folds,y_train_folds)
    y_pred = clone_clf.predict(X_test_fold)

    n_correct = sum(y_pred == y_test_fold)
    print(n_correct/(1.0*len(y_pred)))
```

This outputs

```
train_index 
[19703 19718 19737 ... 59997 59998 59999]
test_index 
[    0     1     2 ... 20026 20027 20028]
0.96895


train_index 
[    0     1     2 ... 59997 59998 59999]
test_index 
[19703 19718 19737 ... 40040 40041 40042]
0.96385


train_index 
[    0     1     2 ... 40040 40041 40042]
test_index 
[39682 39692 39695 ... 59997 59998 59999]
0.89245
```

The second output is using the entire training set for training and then testing the hypothesis on a portion of the training set. Is this correct?

> If so, is this normal/fair/legitimate?

I understand that the sets don't have size exactly 20000 because the method is stratified ( the data is heavily skewed ).

---

No there is not a bug. If I actually calculate the lengths of these lists (although I think they are generators). The length returned as 40000 for all sub-training sets. So the second training set in the out put is

```
[0,1,......,~20000,~40000,....,59999]
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to be complete. In the output there is something like accuracy, but there is nothing corresponding to it in the code. Would you mind to complete it?

Comment: It is from the last line. print(n_correct...)